# User Review - Topic modeling or Intent detection in R

Tags: r, nlp, stanford-nlp, topic-modeling, yelp

I am doing social media analysis in R - something like, reviewing user feedback on a particular business and trying to distinguish a user review to a category/topic(s). 
For example: Find if the user review talks about Neighborhood or Crime etc.. 
How do I find the intent of a given text? To train a model, I don’t have any pre-determined topics with titles. I am performing a un-known topic analysis.
Topic modeling (LDA) can give us several topics (or high frequent terms for each topic) but to identify the topics that were mentioned in the review is hard. I mean, there can be several words/vocabulary that relates to a topic but how do I understand a user review is exactly talking about a topic called "Neighborhood". Any thoughts? Thanks!