# Intent Detection - Text Analysis

Tags: r, text

Trying to get some R code to break down a series of reviews for intent detection (text analysis).  Any lead helps.

This post is similar but has no replies.
[User Review - Topic modeling or Intent detection in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45381524/user-review-topic-modeling-or-intent-detection-in-r)

Comment: removed `android-intent` tag as this is not an Android question.